# Performance handling over synchronized block

Tags: java

In this below code; many of the threads are BLOCKED in my system when adding new conference (addConference() API) into the collection, because of system level lock (addConfLock). Adding of each new conference thread is BLOCKED; and Time for adding conf is increased because of each conference object has to be created/builded from DB by executing complex sql. So Thread BLOCKING time is proportional to DB Transaction.

I would like to separate conf object creation from SYNC block of adding a conf into collection.
I tried a solution; Please guide me if anyother solution or explain me the bad about my solution.

Below is the original code.

```
class Conferences extends OurCollectionImpl 
{
   //Contains all on going conferences
}

//single conference instance 
class Conf {

    String confId;
    Date startTime;
    Date participants;

    public void load()
    {
    // Load conference details from DB, and set its instance memebrs
    }
}

class ConfMgr
{

    Conferences confs = new Conferences();
    Object addConfLock = new Object();

    public boolean addConference(DBConn conn, String confID){

      synchronized(addConfLock) {
         Conf conf = null;

         conf = confs.get(confID)
         if(conf != null)
         { return true;}

         conf = new Conf();
         conf.setConfID(confId);
         conf.load(); //This is the BIG JOB with in SYNC BLOCK NEED TO SEPARATED

         confs.add(conf);
      }
   }

}
```

**//My solutions**

```
public boolean addConference(DBConn conn, String confID){

   Conf conf = null;
   synchronized(addConfLock) {
     conf = confs.get(confID)
     if(conf != null)
     { return true;}
     conf = Conf.getInstance(confID, conn);
   }

   synchronized(conf.builded) {   //SYNC is liberated to individual conf object level
     if(conf.builded.equals("T")) { 
          return true;
     }
     conf.load(); 

     synchronized(addConfLock) {
        confs.add(conf);
     } 

     conf.builded = "T";
   }

   }
}


//single conference instance 
class Conf {

    String confId;
    Date startTime;
    Date participants;
    String builded = "F"; //This is to avoid building object again.
    private static HashMap<String, Conf> instanceMap = new HashMap<String, Conf>;

    /*
     * Below code will avoid two threads are requesting 
     * to create conference with same confID.
     */
    public static Conf getInstance(DBConn conn, String confID){
        //This below synch will ensure singleTon created per confID
        synchronized(Conf.Class) {   
           Conf conf = instanceMap.get(confID);
           if(conf == null) {
                 conf = new Conf();
                 instanceMap.put(confID, conf);
           }
           return conf;
        }         
    }

    public void load()
    {
    // Load conference details from DB, and set its instance memebrs
    }
}
```

Comment: This question might be a better fit for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it possible for you to retrieve the data from the database asynchronously? You could add configurations into your collection, then send the load requests asynchronously. Also maybe getting the information about the conferences in a batch over a single DB query could be a lot faster.

Comment: How to move this question to codereview.stackexchange ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you stated is that you locking everything for each conf id.
How about changing the design of locking mechanism so that there is separate lock for each conf id, then you will lock only if transactions are for same conf id else execution will be parallel.

Here is how yo can acheive it:

1. Your `Conferences` should be using COncurrentHashMap to store different conf.
2. Take lock on conf object which you retrieve from `conf = confs.get(confID)` i.e synchronize(conf).

Your application should perform much better then.

EDIT:

Problem is in this code:

```
synchronized(addConfLock) {
     conf = confs.get(confID)
     if(conf != null)
     { return true;}
     conf = Conf.getInstance(confID, conn);
   }
```

If you use `ConcurrentHashMap` as collection you can remove this, it provides an api `putIfAbsent` , so you dont need to lock it.

Comment: Thanks! Lokesh. But i am not much satisfied. Let see other answers.